# KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer caching the login configuration cause the issue

Tags: java, spring, oracle, apache-kafka, kerberos

KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer will set & cache javax.security.auth.login.Configuration in org.springframework.kafka.security.jaas.KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer#afterSingletonsInstantiated by calling

```java
Configuration.setConfiguration(new InternalConfiguration(configurationEntries));
```

the actual authN/connection will get the configuration by calling org.springframework.kafka.security.jaas.KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer.InternalConfiguration#getAppConfigurationEntry

```java
        @Override
        public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name) {
            return this.configurationEntries.get(name);
        }
```

it works fine unless the application also connect to other system besides Kafka.

In my case, the application connects to both Kafka & Oracle with kerberos authentication supported by spring-kafka & Oracle JDBC driver. JDBC driver has the similar logic to call javax.security.auth.login.Configuration#setConfiguration with Oracle specific configuration. It will depends on who start to do connection first. In my case, if calling Kafka first, then following Oracle, both connection will success; But calling oracle first, the subsequent Kafka call will failed, as the spring-kafka think nobody touch javax.security.auth.login.Configuration, the Kafka login configuration shall be there, but they had been overwritten by JDBC driver.

my current work around:
whenever to call Kafka, code has to call org.springframework.kafka.security.jaas.KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer#afterSingletonsInstantiated first, to make sure kafka Kerberos info there. As it will call the below method in Configuration

```java
  public static void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
        SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (sm != null)
            sm.checkPermission(new AuthPermission("setLoginConfiguration"));
        Configuration.configuration = configuration;
    }
```

And JDBC driver also call the same static method, it seems not thread safe also.

what would be the correct approach to solve the issue?

adding more stack trace:

```
2021-04-02T16:10:41.652-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is /home/vcap/tmp/kafka-client-jaas-config-placeholder200676903256133280conf
2021-04-02T16:10:41.652-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.defaultContext(JaasContext.java:133)
2021-04-02T16:10:41.652-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.load(JaasContext.java:98)
2021-04-02T16:10:41.652-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.loadClientContext(JaasContext.java:84)
2021-04-02T16:10:41.652-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:124)
2021-04-02T16:10:41.652-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:67)
2021-04-02T16:10:41.652-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:99)
2021-04-02T16:10:41.652-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:441)
2021-04-02T16:10:41.652-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:422)
```

Comment: What exact error you are getting while connecting to Kafka? a stacktrace will help. Is it a 'replay' error? Are you using the same Kerberos token for both Kafka and Oracle? Are the SPNs of kafka and Oracle different?

Comment: yeah, I added stack trace for visualize the issue easier. you could see **'KafkaClient'** is missing. It was cached by **org.springframework.kafka.security.jaas.KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer**, but it was removed by JDBC driver.

Comment: someone in my org encountered the same issue, and I revisited the question today, Oracle finally recognize its JDBC driver is root cause of the issue: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2714659_1.html